# EntityQuery, query by referenced entity value,

Tags: 8, entities

I am getting an empty array when I query by the value of a referenced field.

I have the following:

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'custom')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_category.entity:taxonomy_term.name', 'somevalue', '=')
  // ->condition('field_category.%delta', 'somevalue');
  ->execute();
```

Using `->condition('field_category.%delta', 'somevalue');` returns way too many results (nids) than expected.

using `->condition('field_category.entity:taxonomy_term', 'somevalue', '=')`: returns an empty array.

Am I using an incorrect syntax to query by a related field?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1882418) it seems like you only need `.entity` like this:

```
->condition('field_category.entity.name', 'somevalue', '=');
```

Comment: Thanks Jdrupal - I tried that too, and it didnt work. I might need to look into the structure a bit more as the query looks ok to me.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?